# How to use matlabpool in matlab2013a?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying to use `parfor` loop in Matlab 2013a. However, it gives the error cited below when I try to open `matlabpool`.

```
matlabpool open  

Starting matlabpool using the 'local' profile ... stopped.  

Error using matlabpool (line 144)  

Failed to open matlabpool. (For information in addition to the causing error,  
validate the profile 'local' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)  

Caused by:  
    Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient/start (line 281)  
    Failed to start matlabpool.  
        Error using parallel.Cluster/createCommunicatingJob (line 82)  
        The property "NumWorkersRange" cannot be set after submission.
```

Or when I use:

```
n = matlabpool('size')
```

it gives me `0` as answer.

How can I fix this problem? 
My system is equipped with two 2.66 GHz 6core Intel Xeon processors.

Comment: The error message already tells you what to do. Go to parallel>manage cluster profiles. There you chose the "local" profile and press "validate". It should tell you what to do, or at least give some additional details.

Answer (score 0):

MathWorks completely changed the command structure for the Parallel Toolbox. The command you want is [`parpool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html). I'd start from there. One nice new feature is that if you don't explicitly start a pool and then call a command like `parfor`, MATLAB will automatically start one for you.

Comment: thanks alot. I tried parpool. and i am using parfor. But how can i check that how many core of my processor matlab is using. As the performance is not very good. When i review time in matlab, The maximum time is taken by parfor... so dont know why?

Comment: use the command [`gcp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gcp.html). As for your performance issues, you'd have to give more details (preferably in a separate question) of your calculation along with your benchmarking methods. Generally, if your calculation is a short one, then you will suffer a time penalty in transferring date to and from the workers. You only see a speedup if the calculation is sufficiently long that the transfer overhead time is relatively negligible.

Comment: Check the lower right of your matlab window. There you can see the number of connected workers. It should indicate at least two workers, on your system it will probably open more workers.

Comment: I think the problem could what craigim said, that may be due to input output... as in the review the time taken was due to self time of the parfor loop. total time was i think about 1672 seconds, and 1668 was self time of parfor loop. Today i am at home, so tomorrow i will comeback to tell the details... as computer is in lab.... Thanks craigim and @Danial. Talk to you tomorrow....